# SAVON SOAP sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ssl-certificate

I use Savon 2 ruby to make soap call. 
My call code is :

```
cert_key_file  = <cert_key_file>
cert_key_password = 'xxx'

client = Savon.client do |globals|
  globals.log true
  globals.wsdl "#{Rails.root}/wsdl/<-wsdl->"
  globals.ssl_cert_file cert_key_file
  globals.ssl_ca_cert_file cert_key_file
  globals.ssl_cert_key_file cert_key_file
  globals.ssl_cert_key_password cert_key_password
  globals.ssl_verify_mode :none
  globals.ssl_version :SSLv3
end

client.call(:function_to_call, message: function_to_call_body(data))
enter code here
```

the certificate was converted to pem from pfx file . 
Using SoapUI with pfx and password the call works . 
Using the Rails Application i have this error :

HTTPI::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A: sslv3 alert handshake failure

Someone can help me?
Thanks 
Carlo

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
globals.ssl_version :SSLv3
```

try `globals.ssl_version :TLSv1`